# All Ubuntu media players crash upon connecting iPod. How to fix?

Tags: rhythmbox, music, banshee, ipod, amarok

So I just downloaded the latest Ubuntu (14.10) today. I've fiddled with it somewhat and everything is running fine except that every time I try to use my iPod with a media player, it crashes the player. I've tried Rhythmbox, Amarok, Clementine, and Banshee and I've installed gtkpod. I've gotten the updates other forums told me to get. I'm at a loss. I can't go back to Windows and my music is very important to me. Please help.

System: hp pavillion g4 (4gb RAM)

Comment: Is `libimobiledevice` installed?

Comment: Which iPod generation and what is its OS version?

Comment: I am having the same problem with 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10 and 2nd gen ipod There is a bug thread on this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1313430